# NSM error in in EE 5.2.6

Tags: fieldtype

When I go to Channel Manager -> Channels and click Edit (pen) I get this error.

*> Unable to load requested field type file: ft.nsm_morphine_theme.php. Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the /system/user/addons/ directory*

I suppose this is from when I previously had Morphone theme in V2.

Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I  think you'll have to dive into your DB and remove all mentions of morphine in exp_plugins, exp_extentions etc